# Quidquid vs quæcumque

Tags: vocabulary, meaning, word-choice, synonyms

Both **quidquid** and **quæcumque** are ways of translating English *whatever* or *all things that* [sth.], but is there any difference in meaning in that specific context?

I have a vague notion, not based in anything objective, but just in intuition from reading (and maybe so-to-say on an unconscious compared analysis with translations), that quidquid puts a heavier emphasis on variety (any), and quaecumque emphasizes the wholeness/completeness (all of them).

Does that impression have any ground, are they completely equivalent, or is there a different distinction? If the latter is the case, I would appreciate examples, since I think the nuance may also surpass my English skills.

**Update:** when I say emphasis on variety I mean *whatever* in the sense of *any one*, and when I say emphasis on completeness I mean *whatever* in the sense of *all of them*, if my English doesn't betray me.

Comment: There is a relevant discussion [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=1Ki9YSZw3YMC&pg=PA109&lpg=PA109&dq=quisquis+quicumque&source=bl&ots=61M30TyMq4&sig=ACfU3U2DG6eig5CsUeSy2tawULB0185FdQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjWrpX6p-KBAxVaV6QEHWrRCBI4FBDoAXoECAIQAw#v=onepage&q=quisquis%20quicumque&f=false) ; starts p.102.  skimming, it seems that in the pre-classical they used to be more distinct in meaning. where *quisquis* hints to irrelevance: "no matter what"; the diff was blurred later but maybe maintained in the plural - where *quaecumque* has "quantitative sense" (not sure what it means though)

Comment: It is interesting to see how this sentence from *Soliloquia animae ad Deum* (Augustine? probably not but was later 12th century) was translated: *Fateor equidem, quia quidquid facio, quaecumque facio, ante te facio*

Comment: @d_e, nice hints! My underlying question goes precisely in this sense: does a sentence like _quidquid facio, quaecumque facio_ add some meaning or is it just redundant?